# Creating different indent for row names in pander

Tags: r, r-markdown, pander

for the purpose of exporting a results table into word using `R markdown`, I found that `pander` has fulfilled almost all my needs. However, after a lot of searching I couldn't find a way to indent *some* of the row names in my table (the equivalent to `add_indent` in `kable`). For example, the first row's name is: "Level 1", and than I want the second row's name ("intercept") to be indented right. Is this possible? (I found `pandoc.indent` but didn't succeed in applying it on my table).
Attached is the current code I use for the table.

```
library(pander)
set.alignment('center', row.names = 'left')
panderOptions('missing', '')
pander::pander(df,split.cell = c(50,15,15,15), split.table = Inf, 
           emphasize.rownames = FALSE)
```

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK the markdown specification doesn't allow specifying the indentation per row -- you specify left/right/center alignment per column.

Comment: This specific specification or in general? Because I know that `add_ident` in `kable` does enable indentation per row (at least in row names it was possible.

Comment: Ah, you mean `kableExtra` -- which is a great package to generate customized HTML or LaTeX output, but `pander` generates markdown (that can be then converted to other formats) which does not support these kind of things: https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#tables

Comment: Oh, ok. I wanted to make sure I'm not missing an option to do this. Thanks.